# Creating a rule to accept a few variations of numbers

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I would like to allow a user to enter in a SQL limit, such as:

```
# ignore sign, allow whole numbers only
LIMIT 10   # ok
LIMIT 1e2  # ok
LIMIT 1.5  # not ok
```

However, it seems I have cornered myself by defining the tokens as either an `INTEGER` or a `FLOAT`:

```
grammar DBParser;

statement: expr EOF;
expr: 'LIMIT' wholeNumber;

wholeNumber
    : ???
    ;

INTEGER
    : [0-9]+
    ;
FLOAT
    : ([0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*  | '.' [0-9]+) Exponent?
    ;

fragment Exponent
    : 'E' [+-]? Digit+
    ;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

What might be a better way to tokenize this so that I can 'validate' that the number passed to the `LIMIT` is a whole number? Or is this something that should be done downstream by the code/listeners and such?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, or good practice, but one idea is to define the smallest units -- such as exponents, digits, etc. -- as fragment tokens; the basic category of numbers (as you want them) as normal tokens, and then any combination categories you want as parser rules in a sort of hierarchy. Here would be a basic example:

```
grammar DBParser;

statement: expr* EOF;
expr: 'LIMIT' wholeNumber;

number: wholeNumber|decimal;
wholeNumber: INT_NUMBER | INT_NUMBER_WITH_EXPONENT;
decimal: DECIMAL_NUMBER | DECIMAL_NUMBER_WITH_EXPONENT;

INT_NUMBER: Digits;
INT_NUMBER_WITH_EXPONENT: Digits Exponent;
DECIMAL_NUMBER: Digits? Dot Digits;
DECIMAL_NUMBER_WITH_EXPONENT:   (Digits? Dot)? Digits Exponent; // means there's an exponent

fragment Digits: Digit+;
fragment Digit: [0-9];
fragment Dot: '.';
fragment Exponent: [Ee] [+-]? Digit+;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

[image]

Comment: That accepts 10e-2 as a `wholenumber` (and fails to accept `0.5e2`, which is maybe not a whole number, depending on your perspective, although it seems pretty integral to me). Personally, I'd put this in the category of "things you should check after the parse is done because they are clearly semantic", if for no other reason than the possibility of reporting the error as "LIMIT values must be integers".

Comment: @rici -- thanks, yea I agree with you that makes sense.